# Drawing area at Google Map

Tags: google-maps, draw, area

Please see the image :

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20091211-bybjj3qtasrgr1dfaf4c42p39b.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20091211-bybjj3qtasrgr1dfaf4c42p39b.jpg)

Any idea how to do that? drawing an area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The toolkit that allows users to draw polygons on MyMaps has been made available as the [GeometryControls](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geometrycontrols/) utility library

Comment: +1 Re-reading the question.  I realized I missed the point here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to use Google Maps API, check the documentation about Polylines (should be what that is) : http://code.google.com/intl/pt-PT/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html#Polylines_Overview

Comment: thanks, I reviewed the link, but it is not very clear, I could not make it :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate a [GPolygon](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GPolygon) object and add that (using the [addOverlay](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2.addOverlay) method) to your [GMap2](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2) object:

```
var polygon = new GPolygon([new GLatLng(48.922499263758255,-94.921875),
    new GLatLng(49.03786794532641,-128.671875),
    new GLatLng(38.95940879245423,-126.38671875),
    new GLatLng(31.95216223802497,-118.30078125),
    new GLatLng(24.686952411999155,-96.50390625),
    new GLatLng(28.149503211544566,-87.1875),
    new GLatLng(23.725011735951796,-79.62890625),
    new GLatLng(44.59046718130883,-59.765625)], "#ff0000", 5, 1, "#0000ff", 0.2);
map.addOverlay (polygon);
```

The first parameter is an array of points (that make up your polygon), then the stroke (that is the outline)color, weight (thickness) and opacity (how transparent), then the fill color and opacity.

Here is a cut down example:

- [GPolygon example](http://www.cannonade.net/geo.php?test=geo16)
- [GPolygon source](http://www.cannonade.net/geo16.js)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code : This really helped me

```
PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions()
                          .add(new LatLng(34.578289, 36.277231),
                               new LatLng(34.580568, 36.262041),
                               new LatLng(34.549016, 36.287584),
                               new LatLng(34.560977, 36.282660),
                               new LatLng(34.578289, 36.277231));

            // Get back the mutable Polygon
            Polygon polygon = mMap.addPolygon(rectOptions.strokeColor(Color.RED)
                    .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

Reference : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes#customizing_appearances

where mMap is
GoogleMap mMap;
and add : 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolygonOptions;

Hope this will help you