# Inverted Highlighted Area in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, geometry, highlighting, area

Not really sure how to explain this easily, but here goes. I want to make a highlight overlay on the whole Google Map in Android, except one rectangular are which would stay as default. Basically, the opposite, inverted version of this:

[Drawing area at Google Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879566/drawing-area-at-google-map)

Any ideas how to configure this?

Thankyou in advance,
Alex

P.S
Just to keep clear, the example for Javascript is just for picturing purpose, I need this for regular Java :).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Masked Polygon library for Google Maps. https://github.com/vasile/Mask-KML-polygons